# What function will a delegate point two if there is more than one method which meets the delegate criteria?

Tags: c#

A delegate is a function pointer. So it points to a function which meets the criteria (parameters and return type).

This begs the question (for me, anyway), what function will the delegate point to if there is more than one method with exactly the same return type and parameter types? Is the function which appears first in the class?

Thanks

Comment: It *raises* the question.  Begging the question is making an argument that uses its conclusion as a premise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact method is specified when you create the Delegate.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();

private void Delegate_Handler() { }

void Init() {
  MyDelegate x = new MyDelegate(this.Delegate_Handler);
}
```

Comment: It gets more complicated than this if there are overloads, inheritance etc though.

Answer (score 3):

As Henk says, the method is specified when you create the delegate. Now, it's possible for more than one method to meet the requirements, for two reasons:

- Delegates are variant, e.g. you can use a method with an `Object` parameter to create an `Action<string>`
- You can overload methods by making them generic, e.g.

  ```
  static void Foo() {}
  static void Foo<T>(){}
  static void Foo<T1, T2>(){}
  ```

The rules get quite complicated, but they're laid down in section 6.6 of the C# 3.0 spec. Note that inheritance makes things tricky too.

Answer (score 1):

> So it points to a function which meets the criteria (parameters and return type).

Nope.

To add some background to Henk's Answer:
Just like `int x` is an variable which can contain integers, A delegate is a variable which can contain functions.

It points to whatever function you tell it to point to.
EG:

```
// declare the type of the function that we want to point to
public delegate void CallbackHandler(string); // 

...

// declare the actual function
public void ActualCallbackFunction(string s){ ... }

...
// create the 'pointer' and assign it
CallbackHandler functionPointer = ActualCallbackFunction;
// the functionPointer variable is now pointing to ActualCallbackFunction
```